# Apache Beam Python's WriteToBigtable sometimes causes a step to keep running infinitely on Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using GCP's Dataflow to process data and write to BigTable. There will be some jobs that will be run infinitely due to the `WriteToBigtable` process. The chance of the step running infinitely is higher as the number rows to be written gets larger.

Inspecting deeply in to the logs, I found that there is a the difference between finishing jobs and non-finishing jobs as follows –

```
Unable to perform SDK-split for work-id: 5193980908353266575 due to error: INTERNAL: Empty split returned. [type.googleapis.com/util.MessageSetPayload='[dist_proc.dax.internal.TrailProto] { trail_point { source_file_loc { filepath: "dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_operators.cc" line: 2738 } } }']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
dist_proc/dax/internal/status_utils.cc:236
 And could not Checkpoint reader due to error: OUT_OF_RANGE: Cannot checkpoint when range tracker is finished. [type.googleapis.com/util.MessageSetPayload='[dist_proc.dax.internal.TrailProto] { trail_point { source_file_loc { filepath: "dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/operator.cc" line: 340 } } }']
=== Source Location Trace: ===
dist_proc/dax/io/dax_reader_driver.cc:253
dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/operator.cc:340
```

There used to be a workaround to this problem, setting the flag `use_cross_language=True` to use Java SDK. But it is recently disabled on GCP Dataflow (This workaround is used to be working previously)
[image]

Also, I saw that the `2.51.0` is just supported on Dataflow. I'll try this version to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: is this same as https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28715?

Comment: @XQHu Very similar issue. I'll post there too in case my information helps. Thanks.